# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037 1:20 PM

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

In android Studio  last update onwards I am facing the the below problem 
1:Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc000007b
1:22 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

tried several things un installed antivirus,downgraded platform tools from 29.0.2 to 29.0.0 or even 27.0.0...no effect....tried firewall also....no effect.....also try to start adb through command line or direct from platform-tools folder 
only show adb.exe error connot run adb.exe error 0xc000007b
kindly share if you occurred any of this like

> 1:22 PM   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to
>   connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

Comment: At first in reinstalling of win 8.1 the api-ms-win-crt*.dlls are not exist in system 32 folder . In android studio I got the above error plus an alert for crt runtime. Then I copy all of api-ms-win-crt*.dlls from my another desktop computer to the system 32 of my laptop and also I copy the files on folder of abd(inside the folder of sdk).When I restart my win and starting of my android project I saw a little changes in the error:Only error of Unable to detect adb version exit ... . then I try to rebuil the project unfortunately I get Process unexpectedly exit .Do you facing a new solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

You need to reset network settings.

1. Run the CMD prompt as administrator.
2. Enter the command "netsh winsock reset"
3. Restart the computer if necessary

Now if you open studio, there will be no adbhostserver error.